# Spinner custom style is not applying properly

Tags: android, android-studio, android-spinner

I want to apply alternative spinner element background colour, and it works fine for spinner list with limited items that don't need to scroll. when the scroll is possible, the background colour is only applied to text background

[image]

```
        @Override public View getDropDownView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder = null;  

        if(view==null)
        {
            view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.citylist, parent, false);       
            holder=new ViewHolder();
            holder.txtTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv);    
            holder.txtTitle.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,db.getSettings().getInt(15)-3);
            holder.txtTitle.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
            view.setTag(holder);        
        }
        else{       
            holder=(ViewHolder)view.getTag();       
        }

        holder.txtTitle.setText(data.get(position));
        if(position % 2 == 0)view.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(224, 224, 235));
        if(position % 2 == 1)view.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        return view;
   }
```

XML of Spinner

```
            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/pnakshathram"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edittextbackground"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: post your custom xml for your spinner

Comment: does this edittextbackground is what u want to set as background ?

Comment: No, i want that grey colour to that row

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom layout with the background you want to set and then You need to do this -

> set your custom layout in setDropDownViewResource

```
Spinner yourSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.yourSpinner);
yourAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.my_spinner);
yourSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

You need to use your layout in place of `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item`

dont use `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item` use `your_custom_layout_here`

go to your res folder , create a new xml file give any name like my_spinner.xml

**my_spinner.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="@font/clear_sans_regular"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:textColor="@color/warm_grey"
    android:textSize="14sp" />
```

and then add this line

```
yourAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.my_spinner);
```

Comment: yes you need to create a layout with grey background and then you need to use this answer above it will work that way

Comment: @anugrah did you check this or not

Comment: Let me check, currently i am not using setDropDownViewResource

Comment: This is my current code '
Chooselist adapter2=new Chooselist(db, this, my_array1);
  pnak.setAdapter(adapter2);
  pnak.setSelection(c.getInt(11));'

Comment: check updated answer , i added the file also use that it works

Comment: r u able to use this answer as instructed

Answer (score 0):

In your `citylist.xml` you have to make your `TextView` (`tv`) property to `android:layout_width="match_parent"` it will show like exactly you want.

**Update**

```
if(position % 2 == 0)holder.txtTitle.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(224, 224, 235));
if(position % 2 == 1)holder.txtTitle.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
```

Comment: It is already match_parent, and works fine when the list is not scrollable. when scroll appears problem occures